# Getting <select> to update when you add options

Tags: javascript, html

I have a SELECT which looks like this.

```
<select id="mySelect"><option value="">Please select</option></select>
```

At a certain point, my javascript sets the OPTION as follows:

```
var elSel = document.getElementById('mySelect');
elSel.options[0].value = myValue;
elSel.options[0].text = myText;
```

The problem is that you have to click the select for it to show myText.  How do I make it so that myText (with myValue) shows as soon as I run that javascript?

Comment: Where/how is that JS being executed?

Comment: the JS is being executed when they click a button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the jQuery plugin I was using (Uniform), I didn't realize that I had to run $.uniform.update()

http://pixelmatrixdesign.com/uniform/

Answer (score 1):

Add `elSel.selectedIndex = 0;` to the end of your script. Use `elSel.options.length-1` if you're going to ever have more than 1 item and you want to select the last item.

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">
function addItem() {
var elSel = document.getElementById('test');
elSel.options[0].value = '1';
elSel.options[0].text = 'new value';
elSel.selectedIndex = 0;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<select id="test"><option value="1">- SELECT AN ITEM -</option></select>
<input type="button" value="Add Item" onclick="addItem();" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: actually, it does work just fine.  I've posted the entire code example for you to try, also tested in Chrome and the latest version of Firefox.

Comment: interesting, its not working for me.  something I should add is that it's disabled (because of the css) prior to having the element added.

however i find that putting the .disabled = false before the option adding code vs after it makes no difference.

Comment: Why not see if the posted code works for you; if it does it must be some other interaction on your page that you can then focus on finding.

Comment: Tahbaza: Your code did work, and I narrowed it down to a problem in a jquery plugin I was using.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Load the script with onLoad attribute of the body tag? e.g.

```
<body onload="initSelect()">
```

Or simply put the script after the select tag:

```
<select>...</select>
<script>//code to generate the options</script>
```

Comment: The problem is that the JS is being executed when they click a button.  So it can't happen onload, and it can't always happen as in your second example.  Sorry for not specifying this earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Try using DOM manipulation:

```
<select id="mySelect">
<option value="">Please select</option>
</select>
<script>

var elSel = document.getElementById('mySelect');

var opt = {};


opt = document.createElement('option');
opt.value = '1';
opt.text = 'a';
elSel.appendChild(opt);

opt = document.createElement('option');
opt.value = '2';
opt.text = 'b';
opt.selected = true;       /* Here is where we update the select element */
elSel.appendChild(opt);

opt = document.createElement('option');
opt.value = '3';
opt.text = 'c';
elSel.appendChild(opt);

</script>
```

Test it here:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/186012/demos/stackoverflow/select/index.html